# How can the WebClient automatically add folders?

Tags: c#, webclient

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urlDownload), @"C:\Files\Test\Folder\test.txt");
```

If I want to save the test.txt file to the folder, the `WebClient` saves the file only, when I have created these folders `(Files\Test\Folder)` before.
I have however for example the folder `Test` not created, the `Webclient` saves nothing.

How do I do that folders are added automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to check first if the required folder does not exists already, then create it and after that start downloading of the file:

```
string path = "@C:\Files\Test\Folder";
string filePath = path +"\\test.txt";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urlDownload),filePath);
```

more better is to create a method:

```
private void CreateFolder(string path)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```

and call it :

```
string path = "@C:\Files\Test\Folder";
string filePath = path +"\\test.txt";
CreateFolder(path);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urlDownload),filePath);
```

Comment: No need to check if the folder exists. Just call Directory.CreateDirectory(path); directly. The fonction already check if the folder exist