# How do I generate the folder that's in the path name of the file I am downloading

Tags: c#, directory, download, path

So I am currently downloading files from my Web Server and the links to the files are something along the lines of

`var url = "https://website.com/Game/patches/FooGame/App.config"`

and I am currently using

```
 webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(url),Path.Combine("C:\\GAME\\THE GAME FOLDER", filename));
```

The `filename` is `"FooGame\\App.config"`

in hopes of it actually creating the folder `FooGame` and then downloading the file that it got from the url and place it there with the name `App.config` but it's not creating the directory, if I recall correcly it should create a folder based on the name and I **SHOULD NOT** have to use `Directory.Create()`

It's currently throwing an exception saying `"Could not find part of the path"` followed by the path you saw above. Why is that and is there a good way of downloading files and let it create a folder where it should me.

Comment: **[You would need to check first if the required folder does not exists already, then create it and after that start downloading of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951542/1070452)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the WebClient automatically add folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951397/how-can-the-webclient-automatically-add-folders)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you do not, as you can not be sure there even **is** a path in the URL. `my_servername.com/http_downloadhandler?file=` can be totally where you get your file from.

If you want to copy a filestructure, usually you download the folder as a zip archive and unpack it. That is how everyone down to Github does it. And the .zip file can be generated on demand, thanks to the ZipArchive class and the HTTP Filehandlers. Even [HFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_File_Server) has support for [that much](http://rejetto.com/forum/index.php?topic=4790.0).

If you do control the server but somehow can not get .zip download of a folder working, I guess you could use the URL class to extract the path and the path class to work it into the write order. But really, just use the .zip route.

Answer (score 0):

If you call before download file to:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("C:\\GAME\\THE GAME FOLDER", filename))
```

You are going to get:

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

Source: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: See, doing that only creates a folder called `App.config`

Comment: I want it to create the folder FooGame and download the file `App.config` in there

Answer (score 0):

If you create the full path first, then you can get the directory name from that string and create it:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\GAME\\THE GAME FOLDER", filename);
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```